# Adding application specific code to an application module that depends on a library module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a library module in my Android Studio project. Because I would like to publish a free version and a paid version of my app, I've added two application modules that depends on this library project.

If I would like to toast e.g. "FREE" for the free application module and "PAID" for the paid application module, how do I tell the difference of which application module that is active at run-time?

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822672/android-app-versions-free-and-paid-tell-library-project-classes-if-app-is-fr) but I believe that it contradicts the reason for implementing the library module in the first place.

Initially I thought that I would add two different `MainActivity.java` in each of the application modules, each with a different Toast `message`. This did not work, since the library modules `MainActivity.java` was still shown.

So my questions are; Am I on the right path here, is this how you utilize library modules in Android Studio? If so, how do I add code that is specific to the application module, thus not implemented in the library module, "overriding the default" library module code?

Comment: Rather than going with libraries you may want to investigate application flavours under the gradle documentation.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM Would this give me the option to publish my app in two different versions, e.g. two unique package names?

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM If you would post your comment as an answer I would accept it. Flavours were much easier to comprehend than modules, and in my case were more fitting for the purpose.

Comment: That was fast, thank you. Have a nice week!

Comment: That's how I work :-) Happy coding. @MLProgrammer-CiM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than going with libraries you may want to investigate application flavours under the gradle documentation:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-BuildType-and-Product-Flavor-property-reference